# Where does Nami store private keys?

Tags: nami-wallet, private-key, nami

I would like to access my private key from Nami wallet. Where are they supposed to be stored?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet/blob/main/src/api/extension/index.js) for Nami, as it is open source.

Looks like it uses chrome local storage. I believe chromes local data is located in **%AppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage** atleast for windows users.

Comment: In which file ? It's filled with predominantly log files for me

Comment: You'd have to check your extension ID (you can check that in Dev Tools), and go to `<Browser AppData Path>/User Data/Default/Local Extension Settings/<extension ID>`.
In there you'd see a LDB file (viewing it in ASCII viewer will still show you the encrypted private key, that can only be decrypted using your spending password).

But in general, you're better off using mnemonics instead of trying to use decrypted private keys

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had only my mnemonic key and when the coin was no longer supported by the wallet i had to find a private key to get access which I did not write down because I thought mnemonic was enough. I was never able to retrieve those coins after that even though i had the mnemonic and spoke to the tech team. That was with the Guarda Wallet. I think you need both private key and mnemonic as a backup. And this option should be in the wallet interface like every other wallet has. should not have to fish around for it.